# How to hide and show div onselect using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, logic

This is the code i am trying -

DIVS-

```
<div id="showdiv16" style="display:none;">...</div>
<div id="showdiv17" style="display:none;">...</div>
<div id="showdiv18" style="display:none;">...</div>
<div id="showdiv19" style="display:none;">...</div>
```

Now i have a drop down menu from which i am fetching values 16,17, 18,19

and on this drop down menu, i an calling onchange method as

```
<select name="category" id="category" onChange="showSelected(this.value);showSubcategory();" >
```

And my JavaScript function is-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showSelected( sapna )
{

    var myDivs = new Array(16,17,18,19); 
    for(var i=0; i<myDivs.length; i++) 
    {
        if(myDivs[i] == sapna)
        {
            var divtoshow = 'showdiv'+sapna;
            document.getElementById('showdiv'+sapna).style.display = "block";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('showdiv'+myDivs[i]).style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    return false;
}
</script>
```

Let me know how can i achieve this show/hide div effect.

Comment: what exactly is your problem ?

Comment: why are you not using jquery?

Comment: @ryan code is not working so is thr some logical problem with the code?

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot yeah actually i found most of this effect from jquery, but thought to do it in JS only, but oops the code is not working :(

Comment: @Webtecher can you plz explain it little more and with a solution :)

Comment: Wait a minute in my mozilla firefox your code is working properly

Comment: @swapnesh have it in JavaScript :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though `jQuery` would be much easier and cleaner but get this in plain `JavaScript` below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<style type="text/css">
    div{height:50px;width:200px;text-align:center;
        vertical-align:middle;border:1px dotted green;
        background-color:khaki;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="test" onchange="showSelected(this.value)">
        <option value="-1" selected="selected">select</option>
        <option value="16">cat 16</option>
        <option value="17">cat 17</option>
        <option value="18">cat 18</option>
        <option value="19">cat 19</option>
    </select>

    <div id="showdiv16" style="display:none;">16</div>
    <div id="showdiv17" style="display:none;">17</div>
    <div id="showdiv18" style="display:none;">18</div>
    <div id="showdiv19" style="display:none;">19</div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myDivs = new Array(16, 17, 18, 19);

    function showSelected(sapna) {
        var t = 'showdiv' + sapna,
            r, dv;
        for (var i = 0; i < myDivs.length; i++) {
            r = 'showdiv' + myDivs[i];
            dv = document.getElementById(r);
            if (dv) {
                if (t === r) {
                    dv.style.display = 'block';
                } else {
                    dv.style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thx a lot....but one query ..why Keeyai code looks good but not working for me as im having arround 23 divs while ur code works and why 3 === ??

Comment: @Keeyai's code should also work and is more succinct solution. try changing handler on `select` from `onChange` to `onchange`.

Comment: yeah his solution was very appropriate, but your code clicked for me and that's why accepted as an answer :) jquery is somewhat still i have to explore :(

Answer (score 3):

I know this is tagged as javascript and not jQuery, but it's super trivial to do this using jQuery, so here's an example.

```
$('#category').on('change click', function() {
    $('div').hide();
    $('#showdiv' + this.value).show();
});
```

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UBsp9/

Answer (score 2):

My first guess is that you are trying to compare the string result from your select box against the integers in your myDivs array.

Here is some vanilla js matching your original code (although you can really save a lot of headache using a JS lib like jquery, so you may want to look into it).

```
function showSelected(sapna)
{
    var myDivs = new Array(16,17,18,19);
    for(var i=0; i<myDivs.length; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById('showdiv'+myDivs[i]).style.display = (myDivs[i] == parseInt(sapna)) ? 'block' : 'none';
    } // end for i in myDivs.length
} // end function showSelected​​
```

And a js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wyedr/1/

Answer (score 0):

if you can use jquery then you can do something like this:

```
<div id="showdiv16" class='targets' style="display:none;">Div 16</div>
<div id="showdiv17" class='targets' style="display:none;">Div 17</div>
<div id="showdiv18" class='targets' style="display:none;">Div 18</div>
<div id="showdiv19" class='targets' style="display:none;">Div 19</div>

<select name="category" id="category">
    <option value=''>Select</option>
    <option value='16'>16</option>
    <option value='17'>17</option>
    <option value='18'>18</option>
    <option value='19'>19</option>
</select>
```

​and here's the jquery

```
$(function(){
    $('#category').change(function(){
        var divToShow = $(this).val();
        $('.targets').hide();
        $('#showdiv' + divToShow ).show();
​    });
})
```

you can check the working demo here http://jsfiddle.net/H9cvZ/35/

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

[For Sample Code, Check this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umairnoor84/5P2A5/)